# copy from microsoft outlook to JTextArea in java results in illegal character

Tags: java, swing, encoding, copy-paste, jtextarea

I have a Java Swing application for a client that works internationally. A few times per year a piece of text is copied from a Microsoft application like Outlook into a JTextArea, and then stored in a UTF-8 database. Upon retrieval, the database throws an SQL exception that it can't decode some character.

I'm trying to comprehend the copy-paste part of the process. Is there any information about how copying from windows to Java works exactly? Can't find it.

Windows is setup using CP1252, but the text in Outlook definitely is using non CP1252 characters, so the copied data has an encoding. And when that is pasted into JTextArea, does Java transcode that to UTF-16 (it's internal string encoding)?

Comment: Add the exception to the question please. Also, add the table definition and mention the collation used for text fields.

Comment: As a paying customer, I am in direct contact with Informix (or at least their reseller), so I do not need assistance with that part of the problem. It is a fact that wrong encoded bytes are stored in Informix, it does not validate upon storing. My question is about the copy process in Windows, so I can understand where the encoding goes wrong. How do exoctic characters in Outlook (or Word) end up, through JTextArea, in a Java String?